# Trying Google Directory API in android app

Tags: android, google-admin-sdk

I have started learning to implement google APIs to android apps. Currently exploring the update method in the directory API. There is an option to [try it](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update#try-it), before actually implementing and this is the point where I'm getting code 403 after posting an update query, instead of allowing the required permissions. Here are the snapshots:

[image: posting the request]
[image: The error message]

I have put the email-id, (through which permissions are granted) as the userKey

Comment: Are you an administrator of the domain where the user belongs to?

Comment: Yes and no. No because I want to make the app such that a user under this domain can update only his contact and not others. And every user under that domain could use the app. Do I need to be an admin to implement this feature? Yes, because I have the credentials for the admin.

Comment: Only administrators can use directory API. so, no regular users will be able to call any of the resources in this api. Except of the resources users.get and users.list with the parameter viewType=PUBLIC_DOMAIN and only if the contact sharing is allowed.

Comment: Ah, that's bit of a problem. So, how may I proceed if I need to implement the update feature for non-admin users? I just need the privilege of updating a user's own contact details. Is there a way out?

Comment: A possible solution would be to use a service account with domain wide delegation. In this scenario the user would update the information, but the service account then would impersonate the admin and acting as the admin it would make the actual update with the new information.  Check this documentation https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation

Comment: @Gerardo, we tried applying the domain wide delegation, but still a non-admin is getting the 403 forbidden response. Superadmin can do it though. We also tried implementing the same API in a sample app. But there too, even after domain-wide delegation for updating, no one (including the superuser) could update the details. We're using the same method - users.update(). Any thoughts?

Comment: While using the service account, did you impersonate the admin of the domain? Could you update the code you are using for the service account credentials?

Comment: mCredential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                    .setServiceAccountId(<service account>)
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(scopeList)
                    .setServiceAccountUser(<super admin email id>)
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file) 
                    .build();
I used this code for service account credentials

Comment: could you also share the call to the api? I just noticed that in the example above you just tried to update the phone. When updating you will have to send the complete object (even if the only change was in phone). If you don't want to send the complete object, you should use 'PATCH'. then you can just send the field that needs to be updated.

Comment: response = mService.users().patch(email, updatedUser).execute();
Yeah, so i tried using this code for updating user

Comment: Can you call any other method?  like users.list?  Did you authorize your app in Admin Console?

Comment: Yes i did authorized my app, n othr method i used is :
 Users result = mService.users().list()
                    .setCustomer("my_customer")
                    .setProjection("full")
                    .setOrderBy("email")
                    .setViewType("domain_public")
                    .execute();

Its working fine

Comment: @Gerardo.. I tried using this for updation:
 response = mService.users().patch(email, updatedUser)
                        .setOauthToken(accessToken)
                        .execute();

This worked gave me updated response, but then changes aren't getting reflected neither in app nor in google directory. Am I missing any thing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98156/discussion-between-gerardo-and-akeshwar).

Comment: @Gerardo even when i tried doing in try it:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update#try-it
It gave 200 OK response, but changes didnt got reflected in feed. Am I missing anything?